# Satchmo Store KNET Integration

Tags: python, django, payment-gateway

Thanks in Advance

I am doing a project in Django Satchmo Store. For that I have to Integrate KNET Payment Gateway. I didn't get any usefull codes in python for KNET Integration. Which is the best solution for KNET Integration??

i am getting the error url every time even though we are in the test mode

Answer (score 0):

I have open sourced my knet library for python. You can grab it from [my github](https://github.com/burhankhalid/e24PaymentPipe).  The actual library used is called e24PaymentPipe, you should google that for more information.

It is missing one key component (the encryption key); which for obvious reasons I cannot post to a public repository. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: My problem is that am getting the response as an error message. how is this https and KNET related. Does it work in http??

Comment: Depends on what the error is; cannot help you without more information.

Comment: can you please give your email id i will contact you

Comment: thank you for your replies. Please check the details I have added to the question

Comment: You can reach me through github.